# About disabling directory listing in web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, directory-listing

I have disabled directory listing in a folder (named Documents) in my asp.net project with web.config settings below.

It works and http://mywebsite.com/Documents/ does not list the files. But I want the user open a file from this location. For example this link http://mywebsite.com/Documents/file.pdf also gives error.

Is it possible to open a file from a directory which does not allow directory listing. Thanks in advance.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
   <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.  What error are you getting in the browser when you navigate to file.pdf?

Comment: "500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed"

Comment: If you're getting a 500 there may be something in your IIS configuration that is incorrectly set up.  Are any of your other pages on the site having issues as well?  You can use failed request tracing to get some more details on the 500 error http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: thank you very much for your help Jared Shaver.

Comment: My xml declaration had been wrong. It had space before this <?xml version="1.0"?>. Visual studio development server warned about this and I've changed it on the server. Now It works as it supposed to work